# Creating a single json from a combined json list

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb

I am getting multiple json files in a for loop and each json in each loop are in a format :

```
{
    "myproperties": {
        "http.port": "8088",
        "http.base": "/abc",
        "http.path": "test"
    },
    "information": [{
        "abc": {
            "key1": "ghghghghgh"
        },
        "efg": {
            "key1": "value1"
        }
    }]
}
```

and

```
{
    "myproperties": {
        "http.port": "6789",
        "db.base": "tat",
        "db.path": "ghghghg"
    },
    "information": [{
        "efg": {
            "key1": "ghghghghgh"
        },
        "ijk": {
            "key1": "value1"
        }
    }]
}
```

and so on ……….

I **manage** to **combine** all the json in a list out side the for loop and the combine json list looks like:

```
    [{
    "myproperties": {
        "http.port": "8088",
        "http.base": "/abc",
        "http.path": "test"
    },
    "information": [{
        "abc": {
            "key1": "ghghghghgh"
        },
        "efg": {
            "key1": "value1"
        }
    }]
}, 
 {
    "myproperties": {
        "http.port": "6789",
        "db.base": "tat",
        "db.path": "ghghghg"
    },
    "information": [{
        "efg": {
            "key1": "ghghghghgh"
        },
        "ijk": {
            "key1": "value1"
        }
    }]
}]
```

Now I want to make `**single**` json **output** out of this combine json  something in a following format:

```
 {
    "myproperties": {
        "http.port": "6789",
        "db.base": "tat",
        "db.path": "ghghghg",
        "http.base": "/abc",
        "http.path": "test"
    },
    "information": [{
            "efg": {
                "key1": "ghghghghgh"
            },
            "ijk": {
                "key1": "value1"
            }
        },
        {
            "abc": {
                "key1": "ghghghghgh"
            },
            "efg": {
                "key1": "value1"
            }
        }
    ]
 }
```

please note in the **myproperties** section only **unique** and **distinct** node is there.
I am not sure how to begin this with dataweave…  any pointer will be appreciated,

I tried the following :

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere",encoding="UTF-8"
---
payload map {

    myproperties: $.myproperties,
    information: $.information

}
```

But not working

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mapObject for combining properties and flatten for changing information array to single array like

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    myproperties : payload.myproperties mapObject $ ,
    information : (flatten payload.information) 
}
```

HTH

Update:-
For distinct properties you have to get distinct properties first and then map all distinct properties. But you may loose duplicate properties. refer below

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var distinctProperties =((payload.myproperties mapObject $) pluck $$)  distinctBy $ 
%var aggregatedPropertiesMap =  (payload.myproperties mapObject $)
---
{
    myproperties : {( distinctProperties map { // interate over distinct properties 
        ($) : aggregatedPropertiesMap[$]    // map property as key and fetch its value from aggregatedPropertiesMap
    })} ,
    information : (flatten payload.information) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. but how to get only unique **myproperties** fields … for example if "http.port" node is there in second json, it should not repeat... only one "http.port" should come